# How to determine no. of simultaneous users from JMeter load test results

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, stress-testing

I executed JMeter Test Plan with around 3000 users. Test duration was around 15 minutes.

Now I can see in [Active Threads Over Time Listener](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/), that in constant stage there was a load of 3000 concurrent users. But, in that stage users were not continuously sending requests/hits because of think-time implementation.

**How I can find the maximum number of simultaneous users for this specific test?**. Is there any specific listener/graph for this purpose? or do I need to calculate it manually in some spreadsheet tool ?

**Objective is to find the pattern of simultaneous users performing specific action or any action. Lowest and maximum simultaneous users and a graph just Active Threads graph.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found the right plugin, mind the **Active** word in its name.

For instance, on below image there are 101 alive threads as per green rectangle in upper-right corner, but only one active thread is reflected in graph as others are sleeping:

[image: Active Threads Over Time]

You can also run your JMeter test via [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool - the results will be available via fancy web interface, including concurrent users of course:

[image: Taurus Report]

Comment: Dmitri, In my understanding Active here means the live threads. Which have been created by JMeter but have not finished yet. For example in my case the graph shows 5000 threads constantly active. I am looking for a graph which shows only those threads which were sending some samplers. I have implemented think-times at many points in my test and but this does not reflect in the given graph http://snag.gy/nEEDJ.jpg

Comment: Active stands for threads which are in "Running" state. In my example there are 101 live threads, but 100 of them are sleeping due to Timer. The plugin properly reflects the only one thread which is active. Review your timers configuration, perhaps [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) will be helpful